# Easiest way to determine if user is on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop

I'm showing a notification bar on my website, and frankly, it doesn't work well when its on a mobile device. I'd like to show the bar ONLY for desktop users.

What is the easiest way to determine if a user is on desktop or on mobile?

Comment: I think you should use media queries to determine actual capability instead of user-agents to determine supposed capability.

Comment: There really isn't one. You should explore *why* it doesn't work (what feature are mobile phones missing) and use feature detection and media queries to determine whether or not it should display.

Comment: instead of detecting mobile vs. desktop, I think, in your scenario, it makes more sense to detect screen resolution.

Comment: The term "mobile devices" means less and less as device forms proliferate.  Is a Microsoft Surface or Lenovo Yoga mobile?  They've got touch screens and can work like tablets, and they've also got keyboards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Work for Javascript, jQuery etc.

Comment: The supplied code from the link works perfectly for me in an ASP.net website.

Comment: God bless Chad Smith.

Comment: How do you make the javascript version work?  I just get undefined when I run it.

Answer (score 12):

A user agent check is the "easiest", though you could easily employ [CSS3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Here is an example that checks iphone, android and blackberry; you could easily add other mobile browsers.

```
var is_mobile = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone|android|blackberry/ig) || false;
```

Comment: Well I didn't downvote (it looks like nobody did now ...) but your regular expression is a little sparse.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't trying to cover all mobile browsers, just providing an example of how it may be done. I suppose I should have stated that.

Comment: @Pointy very. Did not try for Windows Phone for example. Maybe the media queries is the best since every browser now a days implement it.

Comment: @partho it means "not not"; in practice, this casts a variable to a boolean value. So, any of the following would become `false` (`null`, `undefined` `false`, `0`, `''`) and pretty much anything else would become `true`

Comment: @partho i means case-insensitive and g performs a "greedy" search of the sting, returning all matches instead of just the first

Comment: `g` means "Global", not "Greedy", but yes, it does search for the pattern throughout the whole string and not just the first occurrence.

Answer (score 7):

I find that it's best to use feature detection. Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if it's a touch device. You can do things like:

```
var mousedown = 'mousedown';

if (Modernizr.touch) {
    mousedown = 'touchstart';
}

$('.foo').on(mousedown, handleMouseDown);
```

And then use CSS Media Queries for handling screen width (and it's also easy to detect screen width with javascript). That way you can correctly handle touch devices with large screens, or non-touch devices with small screens.

Comment: ... and you can hide/show/modify elements with CSS because Modernizr adds the class "touch" to the `<html>` element for touch devices. Thus, `.touch #notificationBar { display: none; }` ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading this post 2021, there is an even easier way to find this out.

```
let isMobile = window.navigator.userAgentData.mobile;
console.log(isMobile);
```

The above method simply returns a boolean value.

Comment: FYI: It is 2022

Comment: *SNORT* AUCHTUALLY... IT'S 2023 NOW, BUSTER!
But for real, THANK YOU! I would have just used the big, outdated script

Answer (score 0):

If you use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download). a "no-touch" class will be added to the  element. You could hide the bar by default and add a css rule to show the bar if the "no-touch" class exists. Example:

default:

`.bar{display:none;}`

desktop:

```
.no-touch .bar{display:block;}
```

Comment: that may not be optimal anymore since there are touch devices that are not explicitly mobile --> see surface pro (to be fair it can be a tablet which is mobile), touch laptops like lenovo, etc. and i'm sure a whole new host of touch devices will be coming

Answer (score 0):

If the user is on a mobile device this javascript 'if' will return true.

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') !== -1) { ...

See also: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to differentiate between touch and non-touch devices is using media queries.

1)  CSS to target Mobile/Touch Devices can be written using media query,

```
  @media (hover: none), (pointer: coarse) {}
```

2)  CSS to target Desktop/Non-Touch Devices (only) can be written using media query,

```
  @media not all and (pointer: coarse) {}
```

On Few latest mobile devices (Eg: IOS 10+, one plus etc.,.) hover is detected hence we use, the (2) to identify non-touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const is_mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);

if (is_mobile != null){
    popup.modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Code-only answers are often discouraged.